# Appending Tomcat Console Output

Tags: tomcat7

Running Tomcat 7 on Windows.  I want to be able to "append" all the console output to a text file and found the method of changing the startup.bat file command line of;

```
call "%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```

to something like;

```
"%EXECUTABLE%" run >> C:\Logging\ConsoleOutput\ConsoleOutput.txt 2>>&1
```

This works but wondered if this is the best way to acheive this?  Also, it just makes the Tomcat command window blank.  Can can I maintain the Tomcat command window appearance too?

Below is the section of changed startup.bat file in Tomcat.

Thanks in advance

#

```
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=
:setArgs
if ""%1""=="""" goto doneSetArgs
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%CMD_LINE_ARGS% %1
shift
goto setArgs
:doneSetArgs

@REM comment out the original call line below
@REM call "%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
"%EXECUTABLE%" run >> C:\Orion\Logging\ConsoleOutput\ConsoleOutput.txt 2>>&1

:end
```

Comment: You don't need to do this, see in your Tomcat directory, there is a `logs` folder containing the outputs of your applications.

Comment: Thanks Amine.  Yes I thought that but for some reason my application is not.  The catalina log file is not there, there is no stdout or stderr logs either!!  Any ideas why?  Thanks in advance